# What is the purpose of pyvenv.cfg after the creation of a Python virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-venv

When I create a virtual environment in Python on Windows cmd, in the virtual environment folder, the following files appear:

- Include
- Lib
- Scripts
- pyvenv.cfg

What is the goal of pyvenv.cfg creation? Can I use it in any way?

Comment: Normally, virtualenv is used to manage Python packages for different projects. Using virtualenv allows you to avoid installing Python packages globally which could break system tools or other projects. You can install virtualenv using pip.

Comment: I understand, however I asked what is the point of pyvenv.cfg

Comment: It's just a config file https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments "You" don't use it, but the environment itself might, when activated

Comment: According to this link (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) pyvenv.cfg holds the version configuration of python that you use in your corresponding project.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems though is that the "version=" information lies. For example, in a recent .venv I created for a project it says:

```
home = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.10.4
```

however, when I just installed python 3.10.6, it updates the base 3.10, and now the version info is incorrect. As I am just doing tutorials, I am happy that the environment now has the latest version, but I don't see the point of having incorrect version information in the cfg file.

In looking at the venv/bin folder I see symlinks of python, python3, and python3.10 commands.

It appears that by default on my system the venv is using symlinks instead of copies of the python binaries, which is fine, but if using symlinks, the cfg should not list the subversion number. We can specify that the venv command create copies instead, but my problem is with the incorrect info on the .cfg file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32582870)

Comment: I think that I added non-obvious information to the op's question of what the pyenv.cfg does. One of the things it does is to potentially be misleading about the minor version of the Python interpreter when the venv is created with symlink.

I read the source code, and verified that it does indeed write the version=x line whether the interpreter installed in the venv is a link to the system or a copy. 

I think it's a problem for what is supposed to be authoritative information about the venv configuration to not be. Others may or may not agree, but it's useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

`pyvenv.cfg` is a configuration file that stores information about the virtual environment such as

- standard libraries path
- Python version
- interpreter version
- virtual env flags
- or any other venv configs

If print content of `pyvenv.cfg`

```
$ cat myenv/pyvenv.cfg
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.8.5
```

This is a sample output of the `pyvenv.cfg` file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Another use case, apart from the obvious ones already mentioned, is that if you use the "command" configuration option, you can actually get Visual Studio Code to start your development environment terminal with the virtual environment already activated, as in this example (Homebrew and macOS specific):

```
home = /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11.3
executable = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11
command = /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11 -m venv /Users/<your-username>/<your-project-folder>
```